# Error: The identifier that starts with ... Max length is 128

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I try to execute the SQL statement below when pointed to an SQL Server Express I get an error

> The identifier that starts with 'Select * FROM AvailabilityBlocks LEFT JOIN Location ON AvailabilityBlocks.LocationID=Location.LocationID WHERE ((AvailabilityBlo' is too long. Maximum length is 128." Error.

SQL code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (Resources 
LEFT JOIN 
    [Select * 
     FROM AvailabilityBlocks 
     LEFT JOIN 
         Location ON AvailabilityBlocks.LocationID = Location.LocationID 
     WHERE 
         ((AvailabilityBlocks.LocationID IN (8, 14, 16, 31, 1, 15, 17, 10, 9, 19, 12, 30, 5, 18, 13, 20, 3, 26, 2, 25, 28, 27, 32, 33) 
         AND (AvailabilityBlocks.Type = 3 OR AvailabilityBlocks.Type = 4)) 
          OR AvailabilityBlocks.Type = 2) 
         AND [Begin] < '06-Apr-2015 12:00:00 AM' 
         AND [Begin] >= '30-Mar-2015 12:00:00 AM' 
         AND (WeekDay([Begin]) = 2 OR WeekDay([Begin]) = 3 
          OR WeekDay([Begin]) = 4 OR WeekDay([Begin]) = 5 
          OR WeekDay([Begin]) = 6 OR WeekDay([Begin]) = 7)]. AS FilteredTable ON Resources.ResourceID = FilteredTable.ResourceID) 
LEFT JOIN 
   EmployeeTypes ON EmployeeTypes.TypeID = Resources.EmployeeType 
ORDER BY 
   RClass, Resources.LastName ASC, Resources.FirstName ASC, 
   Resources.ResourceID ASC, [AvailabilityBlocks.Begin] ASC, 
   [AvailabilityBlocks.End] Desc, Location.SubType DESC
```

This SQL works fine when executed against an Access DB. Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try replacing brackets in these places `LEFT JOIN [..` with parentheses.

Comment: Note you should not be doing Select * when tables have the same names. Choose which columns you want to see.

Comment: I got a error like: The identifier that starts with '46,65,29,76,21,13,53,63,26,78,49,79,14,15,54,55,16,17,38,80,59,39,62,56,5,6,11,12,35,60,72,34,69,7,8,71,66,47,36,67,43,41,42,44,' is too long. Maximum length is 128.
But i have used only parentheses in my code. 
My location list has around 100 location id and after 44 it is giving error!

Answer (score 0):

You were using [ instead of ( for the named subquery. I fixed it in the below and added a little structure for readability.

```
SELECT * FROM 
Resources 
  LEFT JOIN 
    (Select * FROM AvailabilityBlocks 
      LEFT JOIN Location ON AvailabilityBlocks.LocationID=Location.LocationID 
      WHERE ((AvailabilityBlocks.LocationID IN (8, 14, 16, 31, 1, 15, 17, 10, 9, 19, 12, 30, 5, 18, 13, 20, 3, 26, 2, 25, 28, 27, 32, 33) 
        AND (AvailabilityBlocks.Type = 3 OR AvailabilityBlocks.Type = 4)) OR AvailabilityBlocks.Type = 2) 
        AND [Begin] < '06-Apr-2015 12:00:00 AM' 
        And [Begin] >= '30-Mar-2015 12:00:00 AM' 
        AND (WeekDay([Begin])=2 
          OR WeekDay([Begin])=3 
          OR WeekDay([Begin])=4 
          OR WeekDay([Begin])=5 
          OR WeekDay([Begin])=6 
          OR WeekDay([Begin])=7)) AS FilteredTable 
        ON Resources.ResourceID=FilteredTable.ResourceID 
    LEFT JOIN EmployeeTypes ON EmployeeTypes.TypeID=Resources.EmployeeType 
ORDER BY RClass, Resources.LastName ASC, Resources.FirstName ASC, Resources.ResourceID ASC, AvailabilityBlocks.[Begin] ASC, AvailabilityBlocks.[End] Desc, Location.SubType DESC
```

Comment: If we're doing things for readability...`"Begin" < '2015-04-06' -- YYYY-MM-DD format, always!` `AND WeekDay("Begin") IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)`

Comment: I suppose you got me there :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses but unfortunately this SQL will still not run, the new error is:

Comment: Actually, use "YYYMMDD" (without the hyphens) to avoid issues with locale/time-zone/culture.

Comment: The column 'LocationID' was specified multiple times for 'FilteredTable'.

Comment: Anyone have any idea why this new error? The column 'LocationID' was specified multiple times for 'FilteredTable'.

Comment: You're using "Select *", which is an issue for several reasons... combined with not using aliases for your tables... so if the column "LocationID" occurs in multiple tables, it has no way to disambiguate them and know which one is which.

Answer (score 0):

There a few things off with your query. I will give you what I think your query should look like. But I believe you need to also be able to figure out  how to break up your query so as to figure out what it wrong

First thing first, make sure the inner query in your left join actually works :

```
    SELECT ab.*  -- Note Here I only select ab.*, if you need any columns from Location then do loc. "column needed"
    FROM AvailabilityBlocks ab
    LEFT JOIN Location loc ON ab.LocationID = loc.LocationID 
    WHERE 
         ((ab.LocationID IN (8, 14, 16, 31, 1, 15, 17, 10, 9, 19, 12, 30, 5, 18, 13, 20, 3, 26, 2, 25, 28, 27, 32, 33) 
           AND (ab.Type = 3 OR ab.Type = 4)) 
           OR ab.Type = 2) 
         AND ab.Begin BETWEEN CAST('20150330' AS DATE)  AND CAST('20150406' AS DATE)
         AND (WeekDay([Begin]) IN ( 2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

Now once you verify that the upper query works, you can embed that inner working query into your left join (I assume that most of the columns are within availability blocks if ResourceId is not then add it via Loc.ResourceID).

```
SELECT r.*,et.* , FilteredTable.Begin, FilteredTable.End, FilteredTable.SubType
FROM Resources r
LEFT JOIN 
   (
        SELECT ab.* 
        FROM AvailabilityBlocks ab
        LEFT JOIN Location loc ON ab.LocationID = loc.LocationID 
        WHERE 
             ((ab.LocationID IN (8, 14, 16, 31, 1, 15, 17, 10, 9, 19, 12, 30, 5, 18, 13, 20, 3, 26, 2, 25, 28, 27, 32, 33) 
               AND (ab.Type = 3 OR ab.Type = 4)) 
               OR ab.Type = 2) 
             AND ab.Begin BETWEEN CAST('20150330' AS DATE)  AND CAST('20150406' AS DATE)
             AND (WeekDay([Begin]) IN ( 2,3,4,5,6,7)
    )AS FilteredTable ON r.ResourceID = FilteredTable.ResourceID 
LEFT JOIN EmployeeTypes et ON et.TypeID = r.EmployeeType
```

Lastly within the "order by" clause use the appropriate alias rather than table names

```
ORDER BY 
   RClass, -- What table has this?
   r.LastName ASC, 
   r.FirstName ASC, 
   r.ResourceID ASC, 
   FilteredTable.Begin ASC, 
   FilteredTable.End Desc, 
   FilteredTable.SubType DESC
```

Being able to break out your queries to see what is causing you problems is key to figuring out what other problems exist (meaning don't expect peoples' solutions to give you the answer, but rather guide you to figuring out the solution on your own)